# CSS styles gone after Ajax call in IE 7

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax

I've had a problem with my styles not being applied after AJAX calls. My styles were not in the < HEAD> section of the page, and they were only recognized by IE on initial Page_Load.

If you know of any other ways to fix this problem, post them here.

This is more of a reference, hope this helps some people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some Googling, I found out that [moving my styles into the < HEAD> tag of the page fixes](http://weblogs.asp.net/alessandro/archive/2007/12/31/updatepanel-css-stylesheet-upon-partial-refresh-bug-in-ie.aspx) the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also grab the style from your AJAX HTML, and insert it in the head.  Here's some sample code.  Tested in IE8 and Chrome.

```
function enable_embedded_styles(html) {
// Grab style content, and create new style element for it
// Works for first set of <style></style> tags in html
// Tested in IE and Chrome
    if (typeof(html) === 'string') {
        var beg = html.indexOf('<style>'), 
            end = html.indexOf('</style>');

        if (beg !== -1 && end !== -1) {
            var style = html.substr(beg + 7, end - 7 - beg); // everything between style tags
            html = html.substr(end + 8); // everything after closing style tag

            s = document.createElement('style');
            s.setAttribute('type','text/css');

            // For IE
            if (s.styleSheet) {
                s.styleSheet.cssText = style;
            } // endif

            // For every other browser
            else {
                s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(style));
            } // endelse

            // Append stylesheet to head
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
        } // endif
    } // endif

    return html;
} // endfunction
```